# What is the minimizer of the matrix norm and it's significance?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, inner-products

For $M_{n\times n}$ a p.s.d real matrix, if we minimize $||M^{\frac{1}{2}}x||_2$ over $x$ under a linear constraint on $x$ as in $Ax=b$, where $b$ is non-zero. what is the significance of this $x$? The matrix square root here is $U\lambda^{0.5}$ from its eigen-decomposition. Does it imply a notion of near-orthonormality to the eigen vectors in $M^{0.5}$? Am confused because $M$ contains the entire set of eigen vectors in it which are orthonormal themselves.

Comment: So you minimize $\| M^{1/2} x \|_2$ such that $Ax=b$? Then, you compute the orthogonal projection of $0$ onto the affine set $\{ x \mid Ax=b \}$ with respect to inner product $\langle x,y \rangle = x^T M y$.

Comment: Yes, that is the constraint. What is $y$ here? Can you write in a bit detail, may be in the answer section?  thanks.

Comment: oh wait. p.s.d means positive *semi*definite right? Then, it is no inner product ... it is still a pseudo metric

Comment: yes positive semidefinite. you mean that this orthogonal projection will ensure that $x$ is "non-zero" vector? Just add in a bit more wording. If so how many entries of $x$ would be non-zero , and what would it depend on?

Comment: it isn't a metric projection anymore, as $x\mapsto \| M^{1/2} x \|$ is only a pseudometric. However, you are computing the minimal pseudo distance between $0$ and the set $\{ x \mid Ax = b \}$.

Comment: What do you mean by minimal pseudo distance ? Note that am actually considering a non-zero  $b$.

Comment: Okay, ignore the whole pseudometric and projection thing. You are looking for a solution of the linear system $Ax=b$ such that the seminorm $\| M^{1/2} x \|$ is minimal. The linear system might have infinitely many solutions. So you are looking for one that is *small* in some sense. For example $\| M^{1/2} x \|^2$ could be the variance of $x$. Then, you prefer a solution of $Ax=b$ with minimal variance.

Comment: What if $M$ was positive definite instead of p.s.d? Then does it compute the orthogonal projection of 0 onto the affine set ${x∣Ax=b}$ with respect to inner product $⟨x,y⟩=x^TMy$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26090/discussion-between-qlinck-and-user251257).

Comment: if $M$ is symmetric, $M^{1/2}$ is also symmetric and $||M^{1/2}x||^2 = x^T (M^{1/2})^T M^{1/2} x =  x^T M^{1/2} M^{1/2} x = x^T M x$. Thus, $\min ||M^{1/2}x||$ such that $A x = b$ is equivalent to  $\min x^T M x$ such that $A x = b$ which is a quadratic linear programming problem.